# For HTML and CSS, if styling a table of product info using table, why not style one row also using a table?

Tags: html, css

I think the conventional practice is to style a table of products, each row having

```
photo        name        rating  
photo        name        rating  
  [...]
```

using a `<table>` element.  That's for the `products` page.  But what about for the `product`page (a single product), when it is just

```
rating      name     photo
```

across the screen near the top, it is one row of the table in the first situation too, so shouldn't using table be a good practice?  Because the conventional thinking is that, in a situation like this, it is more of a layout, so using CSS with floated `div`s instead.  Can this situation really can go either way or really one way is better than the other?

Comment: Do what you think is right, is all I can say.

Comment: @SomeChineseChars When you use a table, you have 3 levels of elements (TABLE, TR, and TD) (an additional fourth level is inserted by the browsers (TBODY)). When you use DIV's, you have only 2 levels - the container and the 3 items. This is simpler.

Comment: @Sime please see comment under your answer... the floating is more complicated, and so is the vertical alignment with the name and photo. (you don't know how to copy and paste my name?)

Comment: @動靜能量 Good idea `:)` I didn't occur to me, because I'd never have to do it before.

Comment: If the information is tabular, you can use a table semantically, but if you want to display that data in a different format/style, you may want to consider *not* putting it in a table. There isn't a *single* correct way to display data semantically, but it does help to construct a format that's flexible for future changes.

Answer (score 1):

Table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <span>Rating</span> </td>
        <td> Name </td>
        <td> <img src="..."> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

DIV + CSS:

```
<div>
    <span>Rating</span> Name <img src="...">
</div>
```

I'd go with the DIV/CSS solution.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/2tXZ6/2/

Comment: it probably will need to float the `div`s, because the name can span more than 1 line, and the photo needs a width and height...  the name should also be vertically aligned with the photo (centered vertically).

Comment: @動靜能量 Yes, the rating and name could be wrapped inside left-floating DIV's. I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 1):

It's tabular data. You can use a table, even if its one row. Semantically correct to me. As far as what's simpler, some say using tables for layout is simpler. Is it correct? Not to me. (...and here comes the HTML/CSS vs. Table layout firestorm!)

If you're laying out products, chances are that its being pulled from a database. Which means it will probably be populating a data table anyway. Use CSS to position and 'decorate' your gridview. That's much easier.